# Inserting CURDATE() and CURTIME() in MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

How do you insert `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` in MySQL?

I am inserting them into date and time fields, respectively in the DB table.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ordisp` (date, time, operator, status, completed, name, email) VALUES (CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".$operator."', '".$status."', '".$complete."', '".$name."', '".$email."')";
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you have any errors? Is it perhaps because of your trailing `,`? Or perhaps because of reserved word usage?

Comment: Please put errors that you get while using above mentioned code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date` and `time` are reserved words of mysql and hence should be quoted with backticks to avoid conflicting with reserved words.

```
"INSERT INTO `ordisp` (`date`, `time`, operator, ....
```

Comment: I dont think so. Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) from Official MySql documentation. Please update your answer before it gets down-voted.

Comment: `date` and `time` are not reserved words. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I am using mysql 5.0, not 5.5. the backticks fixed it. Thanks user!

Comment: @MrCode: True, These are no longer reserved words in `mysql 5.5`. I made a guess that he might be running on `mysql 5.1`

Comment: The backticks alone couldn't have solved this, even on MySQL 5.0 because of the syntax error. Strange - even the 5.0 docs say `date` and `time` are not reserved: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error - a comma on the end of the query:

```
'".$name."', '".$email."',)";
                         ^ here
```

Remove it, so the full query becomes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ordisp` (date, time, operator, status, completed, name, email) VALUES (CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".$operator."', '".$status."', '".$complete."', '".$name."', '".$email."')";
```

For future debugging you should look at the MySQL error, it will give you a description of the problem, for example unknown field/table name or a syntax error etc etc.